# Need to join x axis and y axis label highcharts

Tags: javascript, reactjs, highcharts, react-highcharts

I am trying to join the nodes of the x axis and the y axis of the area spline chart. Here is my [**fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/bgtLs7fr/1/) and also I need to move title and subtitle at the left corner and need to integrate dropdown. Basically I need graph something like this [image].

```
Highcharts.chart('container', {
    chart: {
        type: 'areaspline'
    },
    title: {
        text: 'Total Visitors',
        x: 0,
    },
    subtitle: {
      text: 'This is all users that visited your site',
        x: 0,
    },
    xAxis: {
        categories: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'June', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec'],
    },
    yAxis: {
        title: {
            text: ''
        }
    },
    tooltip: {
        shared: true,
        valueSuffix: ' units'
    },
    credits: {
        enabled: false
    },
    plotOptions: {
        areaspline: {
            fillOpacity: 0.5
        },
        series: {
          marker: {
            enabled: false
          },
          lineWidth: 2,
          states: {
            hover: {
              enabled: false
            }
          }
        }
    },
    series: [{
      lineColor: '#8b8bff',
            color: '#c5c6ff',
            showInLegend: false,
            lineWidth: '4px',
        name: 'John',
        data: [37, 25, 50, 20, 37, 28, 50, 42, 70, 46, 55, 26]
    }]
})
```

Kindly help 
Thank you!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To start axes ticks in the same place set `tickmarkPlacement` to `on` and also set `min` and `max`.

To move title and subtitle to the left corner use `align` property:

```
title: {
    ...,
    align: 'left'
},
subtitle: {
    ...,
    align: 'left'
},
xAxis: {
    tickmarkPlacement: 'on',
    min: 0.5,
    max: 10.5,
    ...
}
```

Live demo: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/w7p6rL8o/

API Reference: https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/title.align

Comment: Thank you can I add the dropdown as well?

Comment: Hi @Profer, I think it will be best if you create the dropdown as a HTML element.

Comment: Do you mean a separate html div and put it on the front of the map?

Comment: @Profer, Yes, I think it will be the simplest to achieve.